# Lightning iframe navigateToUrl not working with Locker Service

Tags: javascript, locker-service, iframe

We're using iframes in Lightning and our links aren't working when locker service is turned on. If we turn locker service off they work fine.

I have the following function which is where the error seems to be happening:

`navigateToUrl = url => window.top.postMessage({ type: 'navigate', url }, '*')`

From my research it looks like `window.top` is the problem, but trying all of the other iframe tricks for navigation aren't working either.

The `url` param is valid. If I use `window.location.href = url` in it's place, the app navigates to the correct url, it just ejects from Lightning and loads in the traditional salesforce.

The ideal outcome here is for the links to load in Lightning.

Error that is blowing when the link is clicked:

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant details of the error message as text, as opposed to a picture?

Answer (score 5):

On the main window object `window.top` is currently blocked under LockerService, but is scheduled to be exposed in Summer '17.